# Colocar Footer abajo de un Div

Tags: html, css

quizá esta pregunta ya la han hecho pero soy bastante nuevo en esto, estoy realizando una pagina con HTML y CSS, tengo un problema al querer colocar el footer de la pagina, ya que este me lo muestra a la par de mi form de login, como se muestra a continuación

[image: mi login]

He tratado de hacer un footer pero siempre me lo muestra al lado, y desde ya muchas gracias

Gracias

Comment: Deberías mostrar tu código, de lo contrario se hace casi imposible adivinar el problema, aunque una forma de solucionar el problema sería asegurarte que los dos div anteriores al footer, ocupen el 100% de la página, pero como te digo, hay muchas formas de hacerlo y no podemos adivinar el problema concreto sin ver el código.

Comment: Puedes usar un grid on dos filas: una con dos columnas (para el form y la imagen) y la segunda para el pie. También puedes usar un flexbox dentro de otro: el externo tipo columna y el interno tipo roe (form e imagen). También puedes usar un flex dentro de un bloque figure con el pie en el figcaption. Si dieras el código que usas podría ser más concreto.

Comment: Donde esta el ejemplo mínimo verificable? Y donde está lo que has hecho por el momento? Y el código? Edita tu pregunta para que podamos respondertela